# vuetify Datatable resets search result each time I click on sort

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I cant filter my **current visible** result in my datatable without triggering a new api call. Each time I click on one of the columns the datatable makes a new API call to the very same page, so its not even appending any parameters to the api call like order desc etc.. So how can I filter my result without making a new api call

My code:

```
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      My data
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
       <v-flex xs2>
      <v-text-field
        append-icon="search"
        label="Search data"
        single-line
        hide-details
        v-model="search"
      ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :total-items="pagination.totalItems"
        :pagination.sync="pagination"
        :search="search"
        item-key="combo_id"
        :rows-per-page-items="[50, 50]"
        hide-actions
      >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="getCombo(props.item.combo_id); props.expanded = !props.expanded">
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.data }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.data2 }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.data3 }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.data4 }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.data5 }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.data6 }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.data7 }}</td>
       </tr>
      </template>
      <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-btn color="primary" dark @click.stop="commentDialog = true">Show comments</v-btn> Tags: <strong>{{ comboItemTags }}</strong>
            <v-btn color="warning" class="right" @click.stop="editDialog = true">Edit system</v-btn>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    <div class="text-xs-center pt-2">
      <v-pagination v-model="pagination.page" :length="pages" :total-visible="10"></v-pagination>
    </div>
  </v-card>

    data () {
      return {
      search: '',
      items: [],
      pagination: {
        page: 1,
        rowsPerPage: 50,
        totalItems: 0
      },
...
...
},
watch: {
        pagination: {
            handler() {
                this.getAllSystemsNewPage(this.pagination.page); //Fetch new data and push into items
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're fetching data from a server and watching the pagination object, it's assumed that all processing (pagination, sorting, searching) happens server-side.

See [this example](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/blob/master/examples/data-tables/server.vue). Everything that happens inside the promise in `getDataFromApi` is a simulation of what happens on the server. You will need to pass along the relevant data from the pagination object as parameters to your server API call and return the correct items.

edit:

How you pass along the pagination data to your backend is outside of vuetify's scope and depends on what the backend looks like. But a simple example is something like this:

```
getDataFromApi () {
  const { sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage } = this.pagination
  const query = `page=${page}&sort_by=${sortBy}&sort_order=${descending ? 'desc' : 'asc'}&rows_per_page=${rowsPerPage}`
  axios.get(`/api/endpoint?${query}`).then(...)
}
```

Comment: But that example always calls the same "api" endpoint. Clicking on any of the sort buttons would still result in getting the same result as before. How do I send the a new api call fo each page clicked? Eg apending ?page=3 tot eh url

Comment: added an example